# XCode 4.3 code signing errors

Tags: ios, xcode, sign

Before Xcode 4.3, I used this method to submit applications to the app store:

-- Compile the application with the appropriate signing certificate which was configured inside the application's build settings
-- Distribute the application into the app store or clients using Xcode's built in submission process. When I was asked to select the signing certificate with which to sign the app, I always selected "Don't Resign".

However, the "Don't Resign" option does not exist in Xcode 4.3. Therefore, my application is resigned, and I always end up with an error saying that the code sign verification failed.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that the compilation errors about code signing are due to a bug in Xcode 4.3. As many other have pointed out in Apple's developer forums, and myself, there are many cases where Xcode will complain about code signing your application if your application contains an image bundle! So, I remove the bundle with the images, and re-imported the images as separate files. I was able to compile the application for Ad Hoc this way, whereas it wouldn't compile with the bundle.

Also, as far as "Don't Resign" is concerned, I noticed that even if the application is already code signed in another step, Xcode 4.3 became smart enough to not re-sign the application with the same certificate, even if it appears to not give you the chance to not to! That's what I have verified with Ad Hoc builds. I will soon try that with production builds.

So, Xcode 4.3 became smarter in one way, and dumber into the other. Apple needs to fix this problem with the bundles, SOON!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Before it used to default to whatever code sign it could find and auto-embed it into your apps. Right now its bugged.

To solve it, you would have to go through the steps of obtaining a new certificate and its private/public key. 3 step process:

1. Make sure you completely delete your old certs and keys by going to Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access. Then Deleting the certificates and private keys associated with your Developer account.
2. After deleting all that info head [Here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) to generate a new certificate for your app. Download and import to your login keychain

3.In Xcode open your project. Head to your root project folder > targets > build settings and attach the new correct certificates to code sign your app correctly.

If you are unsure about the code-signing process. Either go [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood) or go to the dev provisioning profile under distribution you have some (REALLY OUTDATED) examples to point your way

Comment: But won't that mean that push notification certificates must be regenerated? And since in the server new certificates will be uploaded, won't that break compatibility with the existing application already into the App Store? And I don't think the previews version didn't default to anything, unless you have set it to automatic selection. I hadn't done that. I had changed the build setting to use specific certificates, while archiving, I chose the "Don't re-sign" option since it was already signed.

Comment: Yes, you will have to re-generate the push notifications AND it will break compatibility with the existing applications on the App Store. Would I have chosen a different approach? Yes, but after almost a week fighting to release an app due to this glitch I had no choice. And if your code has had its plist file and you didn't previously backed up, Reverting to 4.2 won't work either. (Found out the hard way).